# Main thread usage loop advise needed

Tags: c++, multithreading, message-queue

Im building an app on Linux in C++, and I find it convenient to move all periodic tasks to other threads. This is my first multi-threaded Linux app(and basically first Linux app), and before I used to write multi-threaded apps on Windows but I always used QT, so QT main message loop were occupying main thread. But now I wont be using QT(at least for now, I dont know if there will be any graphic interface at all) and Im not sure at current stage how to use main thread, any advise?

Comment: Do periodic tasks in one or more threads, use the "main" thread for everything else?

Comment: If your tasks aren't actually CPU bound you could also consider asynchronous programming instead of multithreading.

Comment: Moving periodic tasks to other threads is **never** as convenient as you think. Yes, it makes the "periodic" part very easy, but it makes it very hard to stop the "task" part from crashing.

Comment: What do you mean, "how to _use_ main thread?" In one sense, you "use" threads in Linux the same way you've previously used them in QT, the same way you use them on any platform. You use threads when you want them to be doing different things at the same time. Are you maybe actually asking for API documentation? (I.e., asking what are the names and the arguments of the functions that you would call to create and manage threads?)

Comment: If you are comfortable with QT then just keep using QT. You don't have to open a window in QT to use QT.